# Wildcards in Views with CouchDB?

Tags: nosql, couchdb, mapreduce

Is it possible to use wildcards in views in CouchDB?  For example, lets say I have a database that has teams, ages of players, players' averages, and gender of players.  However, the players' ages may not be known - they could be from the Dominican Republic or whatnot.  So I want to use a view with a map function that can accept not having the player's age.  If I want to get the player with the highest average on a team regardless of age or with a specific age, how do I do so if I want to use compound keys?  For example, lets say my map emit function is something like:

```
emit([doc.team, doc.gender, doc.age], doc.average);
```

What do I do if I want to pass in a key to narrow it down, yet still factor in the players who don't have an age entered, so instead of:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5984/savings/_design/players/_view/average?key=["Yankees","male",8]
```

doing something that incorporates a wildcard such as this to get the averages regardless of age:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5984/savings/_design/players/_view/average?key=["Yankees","male",*]
```

Is it possible to write a view in CouchDB to do something like this?  Or do I need to write multiple views and process them separately?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 15):

You can specify `startkey` and `endkey` and use the "wildcard" `{}`, a JavaScript empty object:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5984/savings/_design/players/_view/average?startkey=["Yankees","male",0]&endkey=["Yankees","male",{}]
```

Answer (score 7):

Wildcard is not possible, but you can specify `startkey` and `endkey`:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5984/savings/_design/players/_view/average?startkey=["Yankees","male",0]&endkey=["Yankees","male",999]
```

Comment: endkey=["Yankees","male",{}] should work better as {} is sorted after any number.

Comment: As dedalo and ordnungswidrig pointed out, you can use empty braces as a wildcard with startkey & endkey, so your answer is kind of confusing when it says "wildcard is not possible".